# Nodejs express validator with busboy for files

Tags: node.js, express

I am setting up a nodejs express website and I am using express-validator together with the body-parser(?) to control my input. Now, however, I need to input a file, an image specifically.

From what I have read I need to use the enctype=multipart/form-data to send files. However body-parser does not respond to my using `req.files.profileImage` using a form like so

```
<form method="post" action="/profile/edit/{{profileUser.id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ...
  <input type="file" id="profileImage" name="profileImage">
  ...
```

More code as per request:

Validation with express-validatior

```
module.exports.validateRegister = function(req) {
req.checkBody({
'firstName': {
    notEmpty: true,
    errorMessage: 'Förnamn krävs!',
    isLength: {
      options: [{ min: 2, max: 20 }],
      errorMessage: 'Förnamn måste vara mellan 2 och 20 bokstäver'
    },
},
'surName': {
    notEmpty: true,
    errorMessage: 'Efternamn krävs!',
    isLength: {
      options: [{ min: 2, max: 20 }],
      errorMessage: 'Efternamn måste vara mellan 2 och 20 bokstäver'
    },
},
...
```

From what I've understood body-parser no longer support multipart and recommends using e.g. busboy or multiparty.

How do I access input using those(preferably busboy) and how can I use it together with body-parser and express-validator?

Thank you,
Freece

Comment: Can you post code too, please?

Comment: @aring Not sure what more I can give that has relevance. I added some validation code. All other things are just basic body-parser, i.e. getting info from a post request using req.body.username